# Write to a text file without duplicate or override its content

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList which holds a list of user names.

I'm trying to get the list to be written in a text file, which will be saved and the next time you open the program you can keep extending the array list with users in which the text file will accordingly be extended.

At first it was working correctly, but when I closed my program the list got overwritten as soon as I entered a new user name. I then fixed this with setting appending to true. But now the problem is it appends the whole list every time I add an user, which results in I get a list in my text file of dupplicates. I want it to add a new user to the text file and when I close my program and open it again, the same text file its there and I can still add a new user to it without overriding or duplicate its content.

```
 public void writemedlemmer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {




         try {

            String content = "";

            File file = new File("medlemlist.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


            for (person elem : kontoArrayList) {

                fw.write(elem.getNavn());
            }


            bw.write(content);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should really consider using CamelCase (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for naming things in Java

Comment: Also, the code you provided is not enough to debug it. It's missing two things: how you load the data from the file, and how you update the data in memory before writing it back to the file

Comment: @Dici the user enters through an scanner some infomation which is added to the arraylist like this:


kontoArrayList.add(new person(navn, hold, rekordtid, aktiveår, alder, medlemid))

Comment: If you don't need to have duplicate names (i.e. if I enter `David, Sophie, David, Mark`, the expected output is `David, Sophie, Mark`) then my solution will work for you. You only need to replace your `List` with `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: @Dici The list should be able to have users with the same name. The problem is when I add an user to the list, all the users before gets written too. For example:

If the list contains: Mark, michael, Jones.
and I add the user: Mike
Then the list becomes: mark, michael, jones, mark, michael, jones, Mike. 
But I want it to be: Mark, Michael, jones, Mike.

Comment: I added another solution which supports having the same name for different users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using a List

Since you want to support duplicate names, I suggest you use a list and the following logic:

- when you read from the file, record the current size of the list. Store the result in a variable: `int originalSize = list.size()`
- in your program, ask the user to write new names and add them to the list
- when you're asked to save the list to the disk, only start writing the list from index `originalSize`.

  ```
  for (int i = originalSize; i < kontoArrayList.size(); i++) {
      fw.write(kontoArrayList.get(i).getNavn());
  }
  ```

### Using LinkedHashSet

If you **didn't** have the duplicate names requirement, `LinkedHashSet` would have been a more natural option. I'm adding it to my answer for your knowledge.

- A `Set` is a collection type that contains a unique version of each element you inserted into it, even if you inserted it multiple times
- A `LinkedHashSet` is a specific implementation of `Set` that preserves insertion order. That is, if you insert `a, a, q, r, b, q, s` in this order, your set will contain  `a, q, r, b, s` and will return the elements in the original order when you iterate over it.

That way, you can load the elements from the file in an ordered and unique way, then insert new names at the end of the set, and finally write the output back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should only append the last element of your list (or the element you want to write out to the end of the file).
The other method is to write out the whole list, rewriting the previous list.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, i'm fairly new to java and programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding new element, initialize your list like below,
kontoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();